# Determinants of matrices with a special property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $n\times n$ complex matrix such that, for every pair $(i,j)\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}\times\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, if the element $a_{ij}$ is replaced with $2-a_{ij}$, then the determinant does not change. Let $B$ be the matrix defined by $(a_{ij}+(-1)^i)$. Compute $\det(B)\cdot (\det(A)-\det(B))$.

Regarding the matrix $A$, I have managed to prove that for every pair $(i,j)\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}\times\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ one has $a_{ij}=1$ or $\delta_{ij}=0$ ($\delta$ denotes the cofactor of an element of the matrix). I see no clear continuation from here.

Comment: A potentially helpful observation: let $u = (-1,1,-1,\dots)^T$ and let $v = (1,1,1,\dots,)^T$.  We have $B = A + uv^T$. By the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), it follows that 
$$
\det(B) = \det(A) + v^T \operatorname{cof}(A)^T u = \det(A) + u^T \operatorname{cof}(A) v
\\ = \det(A) + \sum_{i,j = 1}^n (-1)^i \delta_{ij}.
$$

Comment: Could you tell us where you came across this problem?  Are there any particular approaches or tricks that we should expect to be useful here?

Comment: The problem is from a journal for highschool students, and is related to a similar problem proposed at a highschool-level mathematics contest a few months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your observation that we have either $a_{ij}=1$ or $\delta_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$, we note that for any fixed $i$ or $j$, it must hold that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{ij} = \sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{ij}  = \det(A).
$$
As I note in my comment, the matrix determinant lemma allows us to conclude that since $B = A + uv^T$, we have
$$
\det(B) = \det(A) + v^T \operatorname{cof}(A)^T u = \det(A) + u^T \operatorname{cof}(A) v \\ = \det(A) + \sum_{i,j = 1}^n (-1)^i \delta_{ij}.
$$
However, applying the first identity allows us to rewrite
$$
\det(B) = \det(A) + \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^i \sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{ij} =\\ 
\det(A) + \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^i \det(A) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & n \text{ is odd}\\
\det(A) & n \text{ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
In either case, we find that $\det(B)(\det(A) - \det(B)) = 0$.

Comment: Given the context of the question, there must be a way to compute $\det(B)$ that avoids the matrix determinant lemma

Comment: Nice solution! Indeed, maybe there is a way; but the lemma is pretty elementary, a lot of such results are used (as "well-known") in many olympiad problems.

Comment: @JohnnyC I guess I didn't realize how much they can get away with throwing into an olympiad problem, then.

Comment: Unfortunately...